# Starting a PreferenceActivity from a TabActivity

Tags: android, tabactivity, preferenceactivity

I have a  `TabActivity` which starts when the application is launched. It contains 3 tabs. 
I have added a **Settings** option in the **OptionMenu** which when clicked starts a custom `PreferenceActivity`. it is a simple activity which does 
`addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` in its `onCreate` method. However, when the user clicks on the `Settings` option, I receive this warning and nothing is shown at all :

07-07 13:07:56.397: WARN/InputManagerService(110): Window already focused, ignoring focus     gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4075fa28

What exactly is the problem with this? Is there any special way to handle Calling Activities inside `TabActivity`. How to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the using the `xml`, I did this programmatically inside each of the activities and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the intent framework that indicates which custom `PreferenceActivity` to start. Something like below, I think.

`getTabHost().addTabSpec().setContent(yourIntentHere);`

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The tabs are working fine. The problem happens when I try to  `startActivity(this, CustomPreferenceActivity.class)` inside `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that, it should be [`yourTabHost.setTab(indexOfPrefActivity)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab(int)).

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand why I shouldn't use OptionsMenu in TabActivity. Or do you mean I need to call the activity in some other way?

Comment: Is the PreferenceActivity in a tab or not?

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent(currentContext,CustomPreferenceActivity.class);
startActivity(i);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;            // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;                  // Reusable Intent for each tab
```

Then, for each tab:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, YOURCLASS.class);
// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("JUSTSOMENAME")
                 .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The tabs are working fine. The problem happens when I try to  `startActivity(this, CustomPreferenceActivity.class)` inside `onOptionsItemSelected`